# Word for killing group of people based on that group's common age?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes killing people based on that group's age?

For instance, genocide is a specific intent to destroy, in whole or in substantial part, a national, ethnic, racial, or religious group. So it is a pretty broad word including those of any subset of those classes.

It would seem to me that age would be a class. Its subclasses could include, with their respective killing descriptors, unborn (feticide), new born (Neonaticide), infant (infanticide), and the elderly (senicide). I imagine there are additional age groups with specific terminology that I cannot recall at the moment.

So would would be the term for killing someone based on age, irrespective of their actual age?

Comment: I'm confused. You seem to be looking for a word for an intent to kill everyone in an age group, but your subclasses aren't that. For example *infanticide* is not an attempt to destroy all the infants.

Comment: True I suppose, but it was the closest I could come up with. Couldn't they also be used for the mass murder of the respective age groups too?

Comment: I think that the biblical account of Herod killing all new borns is commonly described as infanticide. It is on the wiki page at lease (for the validity that provides).

Comment: *Infanticide* means killing infants, yes. So you might use it there. But even there it doesn't have the narrower meaning of killing all people of a particular age group. In the same way that *parricide* doesn't mean killing all parents.

Comment: It is clearly narrower than any next nearest alternative so far. I would be somewhat pleased with an answer that can get anywhere in the ballpark of what I am asking, whether limited to a specific instance or to all persons of the class. I would greatly prefer the broader word that my question asks for however.

Comment: I suggest you edit to clarify that you are definitely looking for the word for mass killing of an entire age group. But I'm afraid you'll be disappointed. I see there's a list of *-cides* on Wikipedia, looks pretty comprehensive, and I don't see one for what you're looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_killing

Comment: I saw the wiki as well. By removing those age categories, they will simply appear in answers. It's an attempt at preemption. Feel free to edit it to get different responses, but I think this is my question.

Comment: I was thinking maybe "chronocide", but that's just killing time, isn't it?

Comment: I might call it a *culling*.  But there are situations, like Herod, where this perhaps doesn't fit.  I'm not sure Herod culled the innocents.  *Culling* gets at the population dynamics of such a heartless edict, not the political aspects. Doesn't work for Srebrenica either.  But maybe it works for whatever you're getting at.

Comment: I think you are killing the real point of the question by using "killing" as an example case.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the common use of the word "cohort" to refer to a group of people of certain age (in statistics often groups aged 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, and so on) I suggest the word

> cohorticide

rather than "agegroupicide", because "cohorticide" at least is consistent in its use of Latin roots.

Please note that a) I am not a native speaker of English and b) I made up this word, or at least I believe so. However, I would not be too surprised if "cohorticide" had been used already somewhere e.g. in some research paper on such a topic. I just thought it to be a chronicide (thanks commenter H. Licks!) to check this.

Comment: What has *cohort* to do with age-group?

Comment: @kris  As I said in the answer, at least in areas such as demography, sociology, etc. "cohort" is used in exactly that sense: "a group of people in a certain age bracket". Usually those age brackets include ten years, but one could also define other age brackets. In any case, these are age-groups. You can argue that the word "cohort" initially meant something else, but then - blame the scientists who use it that way.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Interestingly, when I google "cohorticide" this answer is the only thing that comes up on google. So right now, this neologism is yours! :)

Comment: Scientists still use it in the sense of the definition provided in the dictionaries, not in a narrow sense, except probably in the  statistical domain in Britain to an extent. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cohort https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cohort http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/cohort.html https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cohort https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cohort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohort https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohort_study https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cohort

Answer (score 0):

Regarding: "age would be a class": Yes, in a sense. But that class can be broken down in various ways, all the way down to "classes" of one-year age increments, so it's not automatically obvious what the relevant categories are.

I think the terms you listed correspond better to the idea of "life stages" - and as you noted, terms like *feticide*, *infanticide*, and so on would apply. As MetaEd notes, those terms do not necessarily mean killing all members of those life stages. To denote such killing, I would imagine the only way to do that is to use a prefix term such as *mass infanticide* or *complete senicide*.

And a very generic way to describe these terms might be *generational annihilation*, *generational extermination*, or something like that.

EDIT BASED ON THE COMMENTS TO MY ANSWER:

OK, let's get to a mutually accepted definition of *genocide* to start with. According to Wikipedia, genocide is: "intentional action to destroy a people (usually defined as an ethnic, national, racial, or religious group) in whole or in part." If you have a different definition in mind, please post it.

But I guess you are interested in an umbrella term for genocide based on age in general, under which the specific subclasses (however narrowly or broadly defined) would fall. I would call that umbrella term "age range" or "age catgeory."

So one option is *genaricide*, loosely based on the suffixes used for *octogenarian*, *septuagenarian*, etc. But that's more about the suffix and does not actually include reference to the term *age* or *age group*. I found some Latin terms that are roughly equivalent to "age group," such as *aetas coetus* or simply *aetate*, but perhaps someone is better at finding a good Latin or Greek equivalent to the general term *age-group-icide*, which I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: I realize that the class can be broken down, similar to how genocide can be broken down into 4 main sub-classes, and each of those can be broken down into further subclasses, and some even more so. (e.g. Genocide > Religion > Christianity > Catholicism). But genocide would apply to the (grand)parent class and all subclasses. Here in my question, we have words that (closely) apply to the subclasses, I am looking for a word for the parent class.

Comment: Good logic. A "generation" is a life-time-long duration, though.

Comment: @Andrew OK, see my edited answer above.